# Concurrency issue with AWS Simple Email Service on Mono

Tags: multithreading, mono, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am in the process of moving a newsletter service from a Windows server running Microsoft.NET 4.5 to a Linux server running Mono 3.0.3. The service uses Amazon's "Simple Email Service" (SES) to deliver the emails, via the [official .NET SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) (wrapping a REST interface).

While sending emails via SES sequentially from Mono turns out to be slightly faster than Microsoft.NET using similar hardware, I am running into serious performance trouble when attempting to deliver multiple mails in parallel. Below is a chart showing the time required to send 128 emails on both platforms using a varying number of threads. As you can see, performance on Mono degrades rapidly after 8 threads, and with 128 threads I get only HTTP timeouts – not a single email is delivered.

[image: Chart comparing multithreaded SES performance on Microsoft.NET and Mono]

Profiling via console output, it turns out that the first "batch" of mails is the source of the slowdown. With two threads, sending one email in each, both threads finish in around 2200 ms. With four threads, sending one email in each, they all finish in around 4400 ms. Eight threads, around 8800 ms, etc. It seems as if the web service, while spawned simultaneously, are run sequentially and are required to wait for one another before returning.

Any ideas what might be triggering this behavior? The [source code for the Amazon SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net) is available on GitHub, but I have not been able to pinpoint anything suspiciously. Maybe the use of the async methods on `HttpWebRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, stop using async HttpWebRequest* for now because there is a [bug](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2013-January/040013.html) being discussed in the Mono list. A patch has been provided, but apparently is not good enough and has been reverted from master.

If you're good with low level code, it would be nice that you contribute a patch.

* The fastest way to stop using the async infrastructure is calling mono witht eh environment variable MONO_DISABLE_AIO=1. By the way, if you're using more than one thread anyway, maybe a Parallel.For would be enough but keeping the code non-asynchronous? The best use-case of async is actually to avoid threading and still manage to achieve parallelization (or rather, avoid blocking waits).

Comment: I have now tried `MONO_DISABLE_AIO=1`, and it does not seem to change anything in this case. Also, after stepping through the AWSSDK code with a debugger, I have not come across any calls to `BeginGetResponse()` or similar. My entry point is the the (supposedly) synchronous `AmazonWebServiceClient.SendEmail()` method. Might it be that I have hit another bug, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the concurrent performance issue using the async methods on `HttpWebRequest` in a tiny test project, and here `MONO_DISABLE=1` does not seem to help either. This seems to suggest, that I actually do hit an async method call in AWSSDK, but I have still not been able to locate such call.

Comment: MONO_DISABLE_AIO, not MONO_DISABLE

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo. The exact command I run is `MONO_DISABLE_AIO=1 mono AwsExperiment.exe` and the setting does not seem to help.

Comment: ok, I was thinking this page was outdated (due to all items except one being finished, look at the end of the page): http://www.mono-project.com/Article:ThreadPool_Deadlocks , but maybe not. You could then try the workarounds that are there, like export MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000 or <httpRuntime minFreeThreads=

Comment: `MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000` does not seem to help, neither with the AWSSDK or with simply doing async HTTP requests.

Comment: ok, as at the end of http://mono-project.com/Article:ThreadPool_Deadlocks (section "Long Term Solutions") there is only one item that has not been addressed, let's try to quickly address it, can you try applying this patch ( https://gist.github.com/4625414 ) to your mono, and then run your test with MONO_DISABLE_WEBCONNECTION_THREADPOOL=1 ?

Comment: I have now run a few experiments using the patch, both with and without the new environment variable. I do not see any change in performance.

Comment: Can you add a Console.WriteLine to the patch to make sure it's working properly?

Comment: We tried this now, and the patch is definitely being used, but still it does not improve performance.

Comment: I don't know what to propose now, try using Mono's generational garbage collector? using "mono-sgen" instead of "mono" (or the flag --sgen to mono)

Comment: did you try the new GC? BTW, FYI I've committed in mono a similar patch to what I posted in my gist: https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/b190db44cbf321391ab0cf946f4501eae76f2eb3 (will be part of mono 3.0.4)